# Angularjs click on a link and highlight a tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to click on a link and maintain a tab active, 
this code are the tabs that are working right, maintaining the tab active:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="MovieContent">
    <li class="nav-item" ng-show="checkLength(movieSessions[mov.ID]['DUB'])">                                                    
        <a class="tab nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Dubled_{{mov.ID}}"
            ng-class="{active: language=='dubbed'}" ng-click="language='dubbed'"> 
            Dubbed
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" ng-show="checkLength(movieSessions[mov.ID]['LEG'])">
        <a class="tab nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Legended_{{mov.ID}}"
            ng-class="{active: language=='legended'}" ng-click="language='legended'">
             Legended
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" ng-show="checkLength(movieSessions[mov.ID]['NAC'])">
        <a class="tab nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#National_{{mov.ID}}"
            ng-class="{active: language=='national'}" ng-click="language='national'">
             National
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my attempt and it is not maintaining active the clicked tab, this code is inside the first tab only:

```
<div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="MovieContent">
    <div class="nav-item" ng-show="checkLength(movieSessions[mov.ID]['DUB'])">                                                    
        <a class="tab nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Dubled_{{mov.ID}}"
            ng-class="{active: language=='dubbed'}" ng-click="language='dubbed'"> 
            Dubbed
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" ng-show="checkLength(movieSessions[mov.ID]['LEG'])">
        <a class="tab nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Legended_{{mov.ID}}"
            ng-class="{active: language=='legended'}" ng-click="language='legended'">
             Legended
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" ng-show="checkLength(movieSessions[mov.ID]['NAC'])">
        <a class="tab nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#National_{{mov.ID}}"
            ng-class="{active: language=='national'}" ng-click="language='national'">
             National
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any perticular reason you changed the `ul` and `li` in `div`s?

Comment: in fact i am duplicating information from the tabs inside the first tab, to avoid users saying they did not find that information so i change to divs inside the first tab

Comment: but can be into any tag so that the link will work

Comment: Does the active class get assigned?
What if you manually add the active class to your <a>, does it get highlighted?

Comment: The active class of the tabs is not assigned, how can i manually add the active class  ?